# Как мне из родительского класса обратиться к свойству наследника?

Tags: php, ооп

```
class A {
    public function getVar(){
        return $var;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public $var = 'Hello';

    public function get(){
       return $this->getVar();
    }
}

$b = new B();
echo $b->get(); //Должно вернуть Hello
```

При этом, мы не знаем название класса наследника.

Comment: казалось бы вам надо переосмыслить принципы ООП

Comment: ну или хотя бы разобраться в отличиях `$this->var` и `$var`